# Is it possible to get .EXE File Version from dropbox link?

Tags: vb.net, version, exe, dropbox

i need to get File Version from some application on my friend's dropbox drive
without download the program

is it possible to get .EXE File Version with URL Path in VB?

Current code :

```
Dim versionInfo = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo("https://www.dropbox.com/s/Link/File.exe")
            MsgBox(versionInfo)
```

ERROR i Got :
System.NotSupportedException: 'The given path's format is not supported.'

Comment: I guess you need to do something similar to this, depending on if you know in which part of the exe the information is stored: https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/API-Support-Feedback/Is-it-possible-to-load-a-small-part-of-a-file/td-p/918. But if the file isn't too big just download it

Comment: do you have sample code?

Comment: No, this is your task

Comment: I'm guessing this is for an update checker. If that's the case, a better way would be to store the .exe-file's version number in a plain-text file and have your application download its contents to memory instead. Your app would then compare that version number to its own, and if the downloaded one is greater (newer) then it'll download the actual .exe-file.

Comment: If @VisualVincent is correct—and I believe he is—you can also look at [Squirrel](https://github.com/Squirrel/Squirrel.Windows).

Comment: Well, Thank you for all of your response, I'll try it

Answer (score 0):

This won't work. You must provide a local filespec to the `GetVersionInfo()` function.

So yes, you'll have to download the file first.

Comment: So, GetVersionInfo() is the only method to get VersionInfo?

Comment: @Wayne ~ You're going to have to figure out three parts for this: 1) Whether [Version Information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/version-information) can work on a partial file, 2) If so, what part, 3) How to instruct Dropbox to send [only that part](https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/docs#files-GET) (it appears to be supported, but there's no direct documentation for it). There's a very VERY slim chance of success on this one, so if you do find a way through you'll have achieved something quite significant. You're headed into uncharted territory.